# how to check if a stream table exists using DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

How to know if a StreamTable or KeyedStreamTable exists? I tried using `exists` and `existsTable` but I am not sure what dbURL to enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `objs()` function, for example:

```
objs(true).name.find(X)
```